# Motorola Mk3000 application development

Tags: java, c++, windows-ce, motorola-emdk

Does anyone have experience developing an application for Motorola MK3000, been reading the manuals and browing the web but can't seem to find a good guide. I feel like this is my last resort. I have a background in c++ and java, anyone can help me? or point me to a good (not confusing) guide? Thanks in advance...

Edit:
Sorry forgot to write what kind of app. I would like to create a bar code scanner that will fetch the image and other infos from server with the corresponding ID, kinda like the one they use in malls to find the item price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are similar topics if you search for them. E.g: 
[How to integrate the scan barcode option on my WinCE application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027493/how-to-integrate-the-scan-barcode-option-on-my-wince-application/28264473#28264473)

If you need more information feel free to ask.